# Adicionar elementos a um array no matlab

Tags: matlab

Basicamente preciso dentro de um for, adicionar elementos a um array ou lista(não sei se tem na linguagem) e depois efetuar a divisão dos valores pela quantidade de interações. Bem simples, se fosse em qualquer outra linguagem, mas como tenho pouco ou quase nenhum conhecimento em MATLAB, está bem complexo.

Até Agora fiz dessa forma:

```
maxInteracao = 10;
for index = 1 : maxInteracao
//stuff

erroClassifTeste = 100 * (classificacoesErradas/numTeste);
arrayErro := [] : append(erroClassifTeste);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue:

```
maxInteracao = 10;
for index = 1 : maxInteracao
//stuff

erroClassifTeste = 100 * (classificacoesErradas/numTeste);
arrayErro [i] = erroClassifTeste;
end
```